# Is there any upfront cost for Azure SQL Database Reserve Capacity Monthly Pay option?

Tags: azure, database, sql

Planning to go with Azure reserved capacity for SQL Databases. Azure price calculator not showing any option to get the pricing monthly as it shows like for virtual machines.

Wants to know whether monthly option is available for SQL Databases reserved capacity and is there any upfront cost involved.

Answer (score 1):

When you sign up for a reservation you select whether you want to pay for it all up front, or on a monthly basis. The price is the same whichever option you choose. If  you choose the monthly option you are committed to paying the monthly fee for 1 or 3 years depending on the length of your reservation.